# how to get groupBy() but in other outcome in javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/groupby-using-array-reduce-8zmi7?from-embed)
And basically it does what I want but I want in parent element (which is grouped by for) to add property name.
Also, I want to reduce some properties in below, like to remove color in child elements, because I grouped by color?

For example, with my data json looks like:

```
"stuff": {
        "onetype": [
            {"id":1,"name":"John Doe"},
            {"id":2,"name":"Don Joeh"}
        ],
        "othertype": {"id":2,"company":"ACME"}
    }, 
    "otherstuff": {
        "thing": [[1,42],[2,2]]
     }
```

or other approach: 
I have an array with one-to many key relation:
[1,1]
[1,2]
[2,2]
[3,2]
[4,1]

How to convert to valid json, with one property in root (first element from an array), and its depended children?

Comment: What does is mean next: `"NotificationGroupId":"1": [{` ?

Comment: The output you are expecting is neither a valid JSON nor a valid JS object.

Comment: thanks, it was a typo. I want to be able to create like these subobjects

Comment: basically I want to create a valid JSON format with sub object with groupBy function.

Comment: @Stefan0309, Can you update with sample expected output JSON?